# MySQL - Producing a list with joins

Tags: mysql, sql

The tables in my database are:

```
students
student_id    first_name    last_name    email    password    reg_date
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(contains 5 records with student info)

subjects
subject_id   subject_name   level_of_entry   exam_board
-------------------------------------------------------
(10 entries of subjects that students can be examined on)

entries
student_id   subject_id   exam_date
-----------------------------------
(links other two tables in many-to-many relationship: 
 one student can take multiple subjects,
 and one subject can have more than one student studying it)
```

I need to create a list of all the students with their names, followed by the exams they're taking. It needs to be in alphabetical order by the student's surname.

I think I need to use inner joins, and probably two of them. I did try this and ended up with a list of the students but each row only shows one of the exams they are entered for.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you show the code?

Comment: Are you not allowed to make a new scenario to learn from? Example, at home try to implement a contacts database rather than an exams database. What you learn from one should help with the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all - tables should have singular name like: "student", not plural like "students".

I also always use only "id" as name on primary key (PK) fields for all tables, makes it easy to write SQL's - but this is just my preference.

Anyway, I continue my answer using your naming convention.

You need a separate id for the "entries" table as primary key (PK), i suggest: "entry_id". All tables must have a PK, and you cannot combine "student_id" and "subject_id" as PK without limiting to one row in the "entry" table per student-subject. I guess one student might take several exams for the same subject. It could be possible to combine "student_id", "subject_id" and "exam_date" as PK, but i guess "exam_date" is a date or datetime datatype and should not be used as PK. Not recommended to have a PK of 3 combined fields anyway.

Your SQL could be like this:

```
SELECT  students.student_id, students.first_name, students.last_name, 
  subjects.subject_id, subjects.subject_name, entries.exam_date
FROM    entries 
  INNER JOIN students ON entries.student_id = students.student_id 
  INNER JOIN subjects ON entries.subject_id = subjects.subject_id
ORDER BY students.last_name, students.first_name
```

The order of tables in the FROM section of the SQL is not important using INNER JOIN.

If you however would like a list of all studens and scheduled exams but you have some student without any exams, then you have to use LEFT or RIGHT join. The order of the tables are then crucial:

Example:

```
SELECT  students.student_id, students.first_name, students.last_name, 
  subjects.subject_id, subjects.subject_name, entries.exam_date
FROM    students 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN entries ON students.student_id = entries.student_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN subjects ON entries.subject_id = subjects.subject_id
ORDER BY students.last_name, students.first_name
```

The latest SQL will show the same result columnwise, but also include students without any exams.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
select students.first_name, students.last_name, subjects.subject_name, entries.exam_date
from students
inner join entries on students.student_id = entries.student_id
inner join subjects on entries.subject_id = subjects.subject_id
order by students.last_name asc;
```